# Merge two map of strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In React Native JSX, how can join two map of strings like this?

```
const map1 = { title: 'Avengers: Infinity War', genre: 'Action, Adventure, Fantasy' };
const map2 = { directors: 'Anthony Russo, Joe Russo', stars: ' Robert Downey Jr., Chris Hemsworth, Mark Ruffalo' };
```

The result I want:

```
{ title: 'Avengers: Infinity War', genre: 'Action, Adventure, Fantasy',  directors: 'Anthony Russo, Joe Russo', stars: ' Robert Downey Jr., Chris Hemsworth, Mark Ruffalo' }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const map1 = { title: 'Avengers: Infinity War', genre: 'Action, Adventure, Fantasy' };
const map2 = { directors: 'Anthony Russo, Joe Russo', stars: ' Robert Downey Jr., Chris Hemsworth, Mark Ruffalo' };

console.log(Object.assign({}, map1, map2));
```

```
Object.assign({}, map1, map2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the object spread `...` syntax:

`const mergedMaps = {...map1, ...map2}`